# Automatic Link Detection not working in NSTextView after programmatically setting text

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview

I have an NSTextView with automatic link detection enabled. When I set the text programmatically `[myTextView setString:@"http://google.com"]` it doesn't automatically show the link.

If I type anything into the text view it will add the link. I want it to add the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up adding a category that would do the job. It relies on a couple other categories for finding and formatting links.

I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/08/16/automatic-link-detection-in-an-nstextview/).

I also put a [sample project](https://github.com/blladnar/AutoLink) up on GitHub.

Answer (score 14):

Had to spent some time searching for solution, but could not find it anywhere.

You do not need any third party libraries. Cocoa will do it for you.

**checkTextInDocument:** works only on editable textViews (Apple forgot to mention this).
Here is code which works if your NSTextView is read only:

```
[myTextView setEditable:YES];
[myTextView checkTextInDocument:nil];
[myTextView setEditable:NO];
```

Do not forget to check "Smart links" in your .xib file

Answer (score 6):

As noted in [a comment on Randall's site](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/08/16/automatic-link-detection-in-an-nstextview/comment-page-1/#comment-2218), there is an easy way to do this in 10.6 or later:

```
[self.textView checkTextInDocument:nil];
```

Depending on how the view is set up, this may do more than just add links—for example it could add smart quotes. You can use `setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:` to specify what you want to check. In my case, I want to have smart quotes enabled while typing, but I don't want them added when I'm programmatically changing the text. So I can use something like this:

```
NSTextCheckingTypes oldTypes = self.textView.enabledTextCheckingTypes;
[self.textView setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink];
[self.textView checkTextInDocument:nil];
[self.textView setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:oldTypes];
```

That will return the field to its previous behavior after the links have been added.

Comment: Use `enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue` for Swift 5. Seems this is not an OptionSet yet!