# Finding links in NSTextView with dynamic contents

Tags: objective-c, hyperlink, nstextview

I have an NStextView that loads a description from a JSON source. The NSTextView loads a different string every time the user clicks a button. These descriptions sometimes have a URL in them which is rendered as plain text and not as a clickable URL. It loads just fine, it's just that URL's aren't recognized. I've set up automatic link detection to no avail. I also tried AttributedString which didn't work, but that may be my incompetence (new to this.)

Here's the code:

```
            if ([firstCommenter isEqualToString:playerID]) {
            NSString *commentBody = [[allComments objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"body"];
            [shotDescriptionTextView setString:commentBody];  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [Automatic Link Detection in an NSTextView](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/08/16/automatic-link-detection-in-an-nstextview/). Hope helpful

Comment: Tried that earlier, didn't work. Tried it again: worked. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

For even better solution without need of any category [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762502/1463411)

TL;DR:

```
[shotDescriptionTextView setEditable:YES];
[shotDescriptionTextView checkTextInDocument:nil];
[shotDescriptionTextView setEditable:NO];
```